# How to query the specific vales in columns form different tables(SQLite)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, table1 and table2. table1 has 'id' column. table2 has 'id' and 'quantity' columns. I want to compare the same values under 'id' columns from both tables and show the value under 'quantity' column form table2.
The simple logic is "select id=1 from table1 compare with select id=1 from  table2, then show the quantity value from table2". Is there any way to query this statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Using INNER JOIN will cause the results to show only rows where the same ID is present in both tables. If you want to show all rows from table 1 and matching rows from table 2 plus blanks for any rows where there is no table 2 id for a particular table 1 id, then use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN.

If you only want certain columns in your output you can list them:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.quantity
...
```

etc

---

#### More about joins - for future learning

In most other database systems there exists the corollary of LEFT join; RIGHT join. If you want all rows from table 2 plus matching rows from table 1, and blanks where there is no related table 1 row, use RIGHT JOIN. SQLite doesn't support RIGHT joins, so you'll have to rewrite your query (swap the table names around) so t2 is on the LEFT. It's the table name that matters, not the order of appearance in the ON section:

```
--all rows from t1 plus any matching rows from t2
SELECT * 
FROM
  table1 t1        
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id

--all rows from t2 plus any matching rows from t1
SELECT * 
FROM
  table2 t2       
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Eventually you'll come across a FULL [OUTER] JOIN which is "all rows from t1 and any matching from t2, plus any additional rows from t2 and their possible matches from t1". SQLite doesn't support this either, but it can be emulated. Ordinarily it's emulated with a LEFT JOIN UNION RIGHT JOIN, but as SQLite doesn't support RIGHT, you'll have to emulate it with two LEFT joins, one with the tables swapped round:

```
--all rows from t1 plus any matching rows from t2
SELECT * 
FROM
  table1 t1        
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id

UNION

SELECT * 
FROM
  table2 t2       
  LEFT JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Cor. All that for the sake of being able to say this in e.g. SQLServer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  table1 t1        
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me further knowledge @CaiusJard